# PHP map() equivalent to parse $_POST vars to associative array

Tags: php, arrays

I need to parse $_POST form vars that were created dynamically using jQuery. The vars have a common structure which is text_id. For example:

```
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_size_23' ]       = large
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_color_23' ]      = red
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_style_23' ]      = classic
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_size_719' ]      = medium
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_color_719' ]     = black
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_style_719' ]     = modern
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_size_501' ]      = large
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_color_501' ]     = white
$_POST[ 'my_app_custom_style_501' ]     = classic
```

Note the numeric ID on the end - 23, 719, and 501. They need to serve as the keys in an associative array such as:

```
$my_arr = array(
    '23' => array(
        'size'    =>  'large',
        'color'   =>  'red',
        'style'   =>  'classic'
        ),
    '719' => array(
        'size'    =>  'medium',
        'color'   =>  'black',
        'style'   =>  'modern'
        ),
    '501' => array(
        'size'    =>  'large',
        'color'   =>  'white',
        'style'   =>  'classic'
        )
    );
```

So I can reference the data similar to:

```
$size = $my_arr['719']['size']
```

Each var starts with a predictable name and ends with an underscore and an important numeric id.

How can this be done using PHP?

Comment: Have you some starting code to show us?

Comment: At its simplest, `explode` by `'_'` and use the last and second-to-last values in the result to index into your array. A slightly more refined solution may use a regex.

Comment: @veve No I do not. I began coding a `foreach` loop, but I didn't know how to get where I need to be. It wouldn't serve as a good starting point at all.

Comment: I think it might be easier for you to send/receive variables through one single array.

Comment: @LefsFlare Do you mean by using associative array IDs in the form fields?

Comment: I agree with @LefsFlare. Why do you insist on making things complex and forcing such an effort to afterwards parse and interpret the names again? Simply create an array using those numeric id's as keys and things are much more efficient and easier to implement.

Answer (score 2):

A trivial [regex](http://regular-expressions.info) [solution](https://regex101.com/r/IlCzmz/1) (though this regex is [quite expensive](https://regex101.com/r/IlCzmz/1/debugger)):

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
    if (preg_match('/([^_]+)_([^_]+)$/', $key, $match)) {
        echo $my_arr[$match[2]][$match[1]];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply loop through your array and use  [explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)function.

```
foreach ($_POST as $k => $v) {
    $keys = explode('_', $k);  // Results in Array ( [0] => my [1] => app [2] => custom [3] => size [4] => 23 ) 
    /* end($keys) would retrieve the last value i.e 23 for first one $keys[3] retrieves result like size, color etc. */
    $result[end($keys)][$keys[3]] = $v; 
}
```

Comment: `$keys[3]` might be a bit unreliable, `count($keys) - 2` would be better.